# ActionScript 3's Bitmap Hittest Collision Checking On Movieclips with Offset

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, collision-detection, movieclip, hittest

I am having trouble getting the bitmap hittest method to work properly on my movieclips. I tried several times using information from different sources, but none worked. I came across a pre-made function that could deal with all the hittest confusion for me, and I tried to use it. I tried it first on a new program and discovered that in order for the function to work, the movieclips must be centered at the top left, but considering that I have to use a specific point of rotation on my movieclips, centering at the top left isn't an option. I also tried changing how the offsets are calculated to see if I could manipulate each to the top left, but it didn't seem to do any good.

I know this is a very specific question, but there isn't enough information on bitmap hittests for me to understand this myself and I think this could also be useful for others trying to use and understand precise collisions.

Here is the code for the *pre-made* function:

```
var _returnValue:Boolean;
var _onePoint:Point;
var _twoPoint:Point;
var _oneRectangle:Rectangle;
var _twoRectangle:Rectangle;
var _oneClipBmpData:BitmapData;
var _twoClipBmpData:BitmapData;
var _oneOffset:Matrix;
var _twoOffset:Matrix;
function complex(clip1:DisplayObjectContainer, clip2:DisplayObjectContainer):Boolean
{
            _returnValue = false;

            _twoRectangle = clip1.getBounds(clip1);
            _oneOffset = clip1.transform.matrix;
            _oneOffset.tx = clip1.x - clip2.x;
            _oneOffset.ty = clip1.y - clip2.y;

            _twoClipBmpData = new BitmapData(_twoRectangle.width, _twoRectangle.height, true, 0);
            _twoClipBmpData.draw(clip1, _oneOffset);        

            _oneRectangle = clip2.getBounds(clip2);
            _oneClipBmpData = new BitmapData(_oneRectangle.width, _oneRectangle.height, true, 0);

            _twoOffset = clip2.transform.matrix;
            _twoOffset.tx = clip2.x - clip2.x;
            _twoOffset.ty = clip2.y - clip2.y;

            _oneClipBmpData.draw(clip2, _twoOffset);

            _onePoint = new Point(_oneRectangle.x, _oneRectangle.y);
            _twoPoint = new Point(_twoRectangle.x, _twoRectangle.y);

            if(_oneClipBmpData.hitTest(_onePoint, 255, _twoClipBmpData, _twoPoint, 255))
            {
                _returnValue = true;
            }

            _twoClipBmpData.dispose();
            _oneClipBmpData.dispose();

            return _returnValue;
}
```

Here is the code to call the *pre-made* function:

```
var inVision:Boolean = complex(visionVector[controlBirds], birdVector[checkLRD]);
```

Here are screenshots of the movieclips:

[Bird movieclip (The movieclip referenced by the birdVector)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ople9.png)

[Vision movieclip (The movieclip referenced by the visionVector)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UEpj.png)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you shared is fairly straightforward.  It creates a bitmap from each of your MovieClips and [checks the alpha channel for overlapping pixels](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#hitTest()).  As you noted, the offsets are your problem, and you need to change the area you sample from.

Reading the API for [`BitmapData.draw()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw()), you can see that the second argument accepts a matrix.  Using [`Matrix.translate()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html#translate()), we can offset the sample region from the default `0,0` coordinates (though `matrix.tx` and `matrix.ty` are the equivalent properties).

The second thing to be aware of is that the `Point` objects being passed to `hitTest()` define where to begin the overlap of the two `BitmapData` objects being tested (since they don't have any relationship to the stage, we have to define where these fictional objects are sitting).  That location needs to be both the `[location of object] + [bounding offset]`.

Below is the refactored function...

```
function testCollision(a:DisplayObject, b:DisplayObject):Boolean {
    var aBmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(a.width, a.height, true, 0);
    var aRect:Rectangle = a.getBounds(a);
    var aMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
    aMatrix.translate(-aRect.x, -aRect.y)
    aBmp.draw(a, aMatrix);

    var bBmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(b.width, b.height, true, 0);
    var bRect:Rectangle = b.getBounds(b);
    var bMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
    bMatrix.translate(-bRect.x, -bRect.y)
    bBmp.draw(b, bMatrix);

    return (bBmp.hitTest(new Point(bRect.x + b.x, bRect.y + b.y), 255, aBmp, new Point(aRect.x + a.x, aRect.y + a.y), 255));
}
```